# How to retrieve objects with a foreign key self

Tags: django, django-models, foreign-keys

I have a model Category which has a FK reference to itself.
How can i send the data to a template and make it look like this

- Category 1

  - List item
  - List item
- Category 2

  - List item
  - List item

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like you're trying to make recursion work in templates. This might help:
http://www.undefinedfire.com/lab/recursion-django-templates/

Answer (score 3):

You might be looking for something like this:

models.py

```
from django.db import models

class Category(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    parent = models.ForeignKey('self', blank=True, null=True, related_name='child')
    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.name
    class Meta:
        verbose_name_plural = 'categories'
        ordering = ['name']
```

views.py

```
from myapp.models import Category # Change 'myapp' to your applications name.
from django.shortcuts import render_to_response

def category(request)
    cat_list = Category.objects.select_related().filter(parent=None)
    return render_to_response('template.html', { 'cat_list': cat_list })
```

template.html

```
<ul>
{% for cat in cat_list %}
    <li>{{ cat.name }}</li>
    <ul>
    {% for item in cat.child.all %}
        <li>{{ item.name }}</li>
    {% endfor %}
    </ul>
{% endfor %}
</ul>
```